# How to remove all navigation controllers in xcode 6.1.?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, xcode6, ios8.1

I am trying to remove all the navigation controllers in Xcode 6.1 and make a new `UIWindow rootviewcontroller` but it's not making a new one. It saying a previous controller already exists.
It's work fine when I debug on xcode 5.1.1 but when I debug on xcode 6.1 it's not working

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using storyboard ?

Comment: Can u tell me the error?

Comment: Nope. I am using simple navigation controllor

Comment: i did not get any error but when i re-initialize UIWindows but i still get previous view controls on it.